# MongoDB printing errors

Tags: mongodb

I am storing an array of object ID's in a variable

```
var skill = db.applicant.findOne({name:"Ivan"}).skills;
```

Now, I want to iterate through that array. For each id, I want to find appropriate document in skill collection and print it to console.

When I do something like this

```
skills.forEach(function(skill_id){
print(db.skill.find({"_id": skill_id}));})
```

I get

```
DBQuery: employment_center.skill -> { "_id" : ObjectId("60938a9e404697a534d18a84") }
DBQuery: employment_center.skill -> { "_id" : ObjectId("60938a9e404697a534d18a85") }
DBQuery: employment_center.skill -> { "_id" : ObjectId("60938a9e404697a534d18a8c") }
DBQuery: employment_center.skill -> { "_id" : ObjectId("60938a9e404697a534d18a8d") }
```

And when I change to

```
skills.forEach(function(skill_id){
    print(JSON.stringify(db.skill.find({"_id": skill_id})));
})
```

I get whole bunch of unnecessary text printed

```
{"_mongo":{"slaveOk":false,"host":"127.0.0.1:27017","defaultDB":"test","_defaultSession":{"_serverSession":{"client":{},"handle":{}},"_isExplicit":false},"_readMode":"commands","promptPrefix":"","authStatus":{"authRequired":true,"replSetGetStatus":false,"isMaster":true}},"_db":{"_mongo":{"slaveOk":false,"host":"127.0.0.1:27017","defaultDB":"test","_defaultSession":{"_serverSession":{"client":{},"handle":{}},"_isExplicit":false},"_readMode":"commands","promptPrefix":"","authStatus":{"authRequired":true,"replSetGetStatus":false,"isMaster":true}},"_name":"employment_center","_session":{"_serverSession":{"client":{},"handle":{}},"_isExplicit":false}},"_collection":{"_mongo":{"slaveOk":false,"host":"127.0.0.1:27017","defaultDB":"test","_defaultSession":{"_serverSession":{"client":{},"handle":{}},"_isExplicit":false},"_readMode":"commands","promptPrefix":"","authStatus":{"authRequired":true,"replSetGetStatus":false,"isMaster":true}},"_db":{"_mongo":{"slaveOk":false,"host":"127.0.0.1:27017","defaultDB":"test","_defaultSession":{"_serverSession":{"client":{},"handle":{}},"_isExplicit":false},"_readMode":"commands","promptPrefix":"","authStatus":{"authRequired":true,"replSetGetStatus":false,"isMaster":true}},"_name":"employment_center","_session":{"_serverSession":{"client":{},"handle":{}},"_isExplicit":false}},"_shortName":"skill","_fullName":"employment_center.skill"},"_ns":"employment_center.skill","_query":{"_id":{"$oid":"60938a9e404697a534d18a84"}},"_fields":null,"_limit":0,"_skip":0,"_batchSize":0,"_options":0,"_cursor":null,"_numReturned":0,"_special":false}
```

**So, what should I do?** (This problem originally occurred when I tried to print all relations of one collection with another collection(many to many))

Comment: Where are you running the query from?

Comment: linux bash shell. MongoDB version v3.6.8

Comment: You are probably running the MongoDB queries from the `mongo` shell. The `db.skill.find({"_id": skill_id})` returns a _cursor_, not a document. To get a document use `findOne`. Also see: [Format Print Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/#format-printed-results) in MongoDB Manual.

Comment: Now it works just fine. Thanks